# Plone 4.0.5, Doormat, default footer and Contact link

Tags: plone, contacts

I would be happy to get some help with the Doormat.
1) besides the doormat at the bottom, I see a "doormat" just above the section:
  "The Plone® Open Source CMS/WCM  is ©  2000-2011 by the Plone Foundation  and friends. Distributed under the GNU GPL license.".
How to remove that on all pages?
2) I happily brand Plone, but I would do it in the doormat - how to remove the "The Plone® Open Source CMS/WCM..." section on all pages?
3) Also I would like to remove "Powered by Plone & Python" (with links) section.
4) How to move the Contact link just a long side the Login link at top.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these "doormats" that you're speaking about are contained in viewlets. You can take a look at how the viewlets are set up on your site by navigating to @@manage-viewlets. From here you can reorder or hide the viewlets you don't want to show.

OR

A better approach would be to create a theme product, and then you can use the viewlets.xml in profiles/default/viewlets.xml to hide the viewlets you don't need. You can also use z3c.jbot to override the viewlets that you'd like to change (like adding the contact link by Login).

Here are some links with information on using the viewlets.xml and z3c.jbot.

[z3c.jbot](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot) (from pypy)
[viewlets.xml](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customizing-main-template-viewlets/reordering-and-hiding-viewlets) (from plone.org documentation)

Hopefully this is helpful for you.